# How to loop through data in jQote2 within template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to start using jQote2 for javascript templating, I have read official documentation of api, but I'm still in the dark how you loop through data in my templates?

My js code:

```
$(function() {
    var data, tmpl, html;

    data = {
        header: "Header for template",
        list:   ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'js_templates/first.html',
        async: false
    }).done(function(d){
        tmpl = d;
    });

    html = $.jqote(tmpl, data);

    console.log(html);

});
```

My template first.html:

```
<div>
    <h1><%=this.header%></h1>
    // I want to loop trough list here??
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have no idea what your Json data looks like, but here's a snippet from one of my jqote template files that loops through and renderes table rows:

```
<table>
    <% for(d=0;d<this.Vehicles.length;d++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= this.Vehicles[d].Info.Year %></td>
            <td><%= this.Vehicles[d].Info.Make %></td>
            <td><%= this.Vehicles[d].Info.Model %></td>
            <td><%= this.Vehicles[d].Info.Vin.Number %></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks that's it. I guess i missed concept that you can use any regular javascript functions in templates. Could i also use jquery functions in my templates? Like `$.each()`?

Comment: @arma I think you answered your own question.

Comment: @arma By the way, I've had some experience with a couple different javascript template libraries and while jqote isn't bad I found I liked underscore's templates alot more.

Comment: Having JavaScript inside a template sure is powerful but it actually defeats the object of templates.

Comment: @Marc I would not disagree with you at all.